# Activity not receiving callback from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback

I have a `Fragment` that interfaces `OnWeekViewClickListener` as such:

```
  public interface OnWeekViewClickListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onWeekViewClick();
}
```

I assign the listener during the `onAttach` method as such:

```
  @Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.activity = activity;
    try {
        mListener = (OnWeekViewClickListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

yet my `Activity` that `implements OnWeekViewClickListener` never receives a call back? Nor any errors?

Here is that activity:

```
  public class RoomDetailsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements RoomAmenityHorizontalViewer.OnFragmentInteractionListener, DayScheduleViewer.OnWeekViewClickListener {
        private RoomAmenityHorizontalViewer amenityFrag = RoomAmenityHorizontalViewer.newInstance();
    private DayScheduleViewer dayFrag = DayScheduleViewer.newInstance();
    private FrameLayout dayViewFrame;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_view_info);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.room_amenity_spinner_view, amenityFrag, "amenityFrag");
        transaction.replace(R.id.room_dayview_layout, dayFrag, "dayFrag");
        transaction.commit();

        ImageButton backButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.roomDetailsBackBtn);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myBackIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ProximityActivity.class);
                startActivity(myBackIntent);
            }
        });

        RoundedImageView pinOverlay = (RoundedImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

        ImageView roomImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.roomImageView);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_room_details, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onWeekViewClick() {
        Log.v("Fragment Interaction", "Fragment item touched!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
    }
}
```

Here the fragment is calling the listener:

```
  myWeekView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onWeekViewClick();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, fixed the format.

Comment: are you calling `mListener.onWeekViewClick()` anywhere in your `Fragment`?

Comment: Yes, it is called from a view's "OnClick" event. I will add that,

Comment: it looks good. Are you sure the logcat is working and you are not filtering it ?

Comment: Yes, I am using a custom WeekView UI https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View. 
I tried enabling Clickable on them as well. Still nothing. And I am not filtering so I am stumped.

Comment: I just tested out the `onClick` and apparently that method isn't even calling. Not certain why.

Comment: looking at the library, it looks like you have to call `setOnEventClickListener`. Try with this one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83895/discussion-between-tukajo-and-blackbelt).